# Testing File Upload Functionality

Tags: vulnerability, file-upload

I want to test a file upload functionality and I wasn't able to upload exe files, but I could upload file.exe.jpg (adding jpg extension). What threat this file possesses after it uploaded on the server?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise but maybe this will help you: [Block upload of executable images (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851976/block-upload-of-executable-images-php)

Comment: I do not see an immediate thread when an executable is uploaded to a server with the file extension .jpg 

However, it is recommended to determine header of the uploaded file. This can be done by checking the mime type (mime_content_type)

If the PHP version is older, you can try to perform null byte injection. E.g. upload a file called "myfile.exe%00.jpg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First as a little sidenote, a xyz.exe.com.bat.jpg file could be a technically valid image file, and should not be blocked for upload unless you willingly want to limit functionalities (which could be acceptable - just saying)

Now to answer your question : a xyz.exe.jpg file or a xyz.jpg file pose almost the same threat after having been uploaded to your server.

First, what additional threat would a malware *executable* file have, somewhat disguised by appending `.jpg` at the end ?
If your application simply parses images (without trying to execute the content of the images as binary, which is probably the case of 99,9999% of apps) to display them, or simply transmits them over the wire (for a simple website), there is no additional risk due to an automated process (displaying, transferring..). 
The only additional risk would occur if a curious person would rename the file into a `.exe` extension and run it willingly on a machine ***as an executable file***

Now, a technically displayable (or simply a file finishing with `.jpg`) image could leverage a bug in an image parsing piece of code (typically a library that you would use to, for example, crop or resize images). In such a case, a `.exe.jpg` disguised ***executable*** would not have any effect on the parser. Only a carefully crafted file, tailored especially for the library that you use, would be able to leverage anything, and that would happen during the parsing.

To sum it up : a `.exe.jpg` ***executable*** processed by a normal image parsing piece of code is harmless, since it would not be ***executed*** by the parsing code

As a final note, checking if the file is indeed a technically valid image before doing any further processing is generally a good idea, if you have enough resources to do so. Again, in such a case, a bug in the "file type checker" library could be leveraged. But at least, a xyz.exe.jpg executable would not pass validation

Comment: Right. However, if there is another vulnerability in the system (for example, a *local file inclusion vulnerability*), then the situation might be different and the manipulated file could be used for a more advanced attack.